# Text Mode Installation Of Ubuntu Server 13.10 With No Graphical Screens At the Installation Time

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, syslinux

I am doing Ubuntu Server Installation, At this time when i just start installation of Ubuntu Server 13.10, I see Graphics, Is this possible to remove graphics and and only command line installations?

My Syslinux.cfg looks like this:

```
timeout 1
default /install/vmlinuz
append initrd=/install/initrd.gz preseed/file=/hd-media/preseed.cfg locale=en_US console- keymaps-at/keymap=us languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=US vga=normal priority=critical
```

Edit:

I am talking about ; Ubuntu Server installations start with graphical boot loading then yes no questions so instead to those graphical environment i wants only Text Mode installation, So now question is more clear...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong install media. The Server Edition ISO does not use a graphical installer program. The server edition uses a text based menu based process for the install.

From: https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html

> Unlike the Desktop Edition, the Server Edition does not include a graphical installation program. The Server Edition uses a console menu based process instead.

edit:
While this may look like a "graphical" installer, it's all a text based menu system.
[image]

Comment: The screen which you gave here i termed as Graphical, In my Non graphical means pure written text based installation on black terminal.